# Getting 204 and no response on Bulk API v2 query

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api, bulk-api-v2

I am trying to get the result for query 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account' using bulk API v2. I am getting the job id and state as UploadComplete but when I am trying to get the results for the job I am getting 204 with no errors but also no data.

Comment: sometimes it's giving the data and sometimes it's not

Comment: Same to me while using this kind of query SELECT Id, PersonContactId FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('0017A0xxxxxx..','0017A00xxx....')
Inconsistent behavior's, for same query I could receive or not the csv file response even in previous rest request for geting job status I receive "state": "JobComplete"!